# ROS2/Gazebo/ros2_control: Class gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem does not exist

Tags: gazebo, ros2, plugin, yaml, ros2-control

please excuse if i did not find the correct Thread with a similar problem. After multiple days searching for an answer i decided to post my concrete question.

My setup:
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
ROS2 Foxy
Gazebo 11.13.0
installed via sudo apt-get -y install ros-foxy-gazebo

Inside my URDF File i configured ros2_control as follows:

```
  <ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">

    <hardware>
      <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
      <!-- <plugin>test_system</plugin> -->
    </hardware> 

    <joint name="Joint11_Grundplatte_Bizeps1">
      <command_interface name="position">
        <!-- <param name="min">-0.5236</param>        <!-- -0.5236 = -30° -->
        <param name="max">1.3963</param>        <!--1.3963 = +80° -->
      </command_interface>

      <state_interface name="position"/>
    </joint>

  </ros2_control>
```

I also added the gazebo_ros2_control plugin to the URDF file:

```
  <gazebo>
    <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control"> 
      <parameters>$(find model_picker_description)/config/picker_controllers.yaml</parameters>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
```

And thats the used config file `picker_controllers.yaml` :

```
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 10  # Hz
    #use_sim_time: True

    #Publisher für Joint states
    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

    #"forward_position_controller" ist ein "single joint"-controller aus dem package "ros2_controllers". Ich denke der ist richtig für mich.
    bizeps_position_controller:
      type: forward_command_controller/ForwardCommandController

bizeps_position_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    #Für den ForwardCommandController sind das alle möglichen Parameter. 
    #siehe: https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_controllers/blob/master/forward_command_controller/src/forward_command_controller_parameters.yaml
    joints: Joint11_Grundplatte_Bizeps1
    interface_name: position
```

Now lets get into the issue:
I am starting my Simulations within two steps. First Step starts gazebo with an empty world. Second Step spawns my Models, starts Nodes, ... . During the First Step everything is fine. In my second Step when using the ros2_control hardware plugin gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem im getting the following error:

```
[ros2_control_node-2] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pluginlib::LibraryLoadException'
[ros2_control_node-2]   what():  According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem with base class type hardware_interface::SystemInterface does not exist. Declared types are  fake_components/GenericSystem test_hardware_components/TestSystemCommandModes test_hardware_components/TestTwoJointSystem test_system
[ERROR] [ros2_control_node-2]: process has died [pid 26536, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/foxy/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params_h9xe6lfo --params-file /home/Stefan/share/ros2_ws_raf/install/model_picker_description/share/model_picker_description/config/picker_controllers.yaml'].
```

In the CLI where gazebo with the empty world starts in Step 1 i am also getting the following error:

```
[gzserver-1] [ERROR] [1701789856.549460633] [gazebo_ros2_control]: parser error Couldn't parse params file: '--params-file $(find model_picker_description)/config/picker_controllers.yaml'. Error: Error opening YAML file, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-rcl-yaml-param-parser-1.1.14/src/parser.c:198, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-rcl-1.1.14/src/rcl/arguments.c:388
[gzserver-1]
```

In my gzserver Log-Files (~/.gazebo/server-11345$ nano default.log) there is no error message:

```
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.13.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org


(1701789841 86590197) [Msg] Waiting for master.
(1701789841 95590670) [Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
(1701789841 95688797) [Msg] Publicized address: 172.21.0.2
(1701789841 327159780) [Msg] Loading world file [/home/Stefan/share/ros2_ws_raf/install/raf_gazebo/share/raf_gazebo/worlds/raf_empty.world]
(1701789841 393870146) Init world[default]
```

When i search for the gazebo_ros2_control package i find inside `/opt/ros/foxy/share/gazebo_ros2_control/gazebo_hardware_plugins.xml` this:

```
<library path="gazebo_hardware_plugins">
  <class
    name="gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem"
    type="gazebo_ros2_control::GazeboSystem"
    base_class_type="gazebo_ros2_control::GazeboSystemInterface">
    <description>
      GazeboPositionJoint
    </description>
  </class>
</library>
```

I am just a beginner but this tells me, that the plugin should be available.

I also added the path to the plugin into the environment variable "GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH", but nothing changed.

So at this point i’m totally confused, because in my opinion the interfaces aren’t missing. I am trying to use the gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem for the control of revolute Joints of a Delta Picker.

Can anyone help me out? Any hint is appreciated.
Thanks alot in advance.

P.S. If any further documentation or log-files are needed just say so - i’m quiet new to this.

Yours sincerely

Spezies31

**Additional Information after initial Post:**

**Code of Launch-File #1:**
First Launch-File "`start_world.launch.py`" starts gazebo with an empty world:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_prefix

def generate_launch_description():
    
    pkg_gazebo_ros = get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros')# Get the Path to Package "gazebo_ros". Evtl. anderer Package Name notwendig (vllt. "ros-foxy-gazebo")
    pkg_box_bot_gazebo = get_package_share_directory('raf_gazebo') # Get the Path to Package "raf_gazebo".

    #We get the whole install dir
    #We do this to avoid having to copy or softlink manually the packages so that gazebo can find them
    description_package_name = "raf_gazebo"
    install_dir = get_package_prefix(description_package_name) # Get the Path to the Install directory of the Packages "raf_gazebo"
    
    # Set the path to the WORLD model files. Is to find the models inside the models folder in raf_gazebo package
    gazebo_models_path = os.path.join(pkg_box_bot_gazebo, 'models') # Generating the Path "gazebo_models_path" by appending 'models' to 'pkg_box_bot_gazebo'
    # os.environ["GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH"] = gazebo_models_path

    if 'GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH' in os.environ: #Add Gazebo Model Path to "GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH". So Gazebo can load the models. Otherwise gazebo is not able to find them.
        os.environ['GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH'] = os.environ['GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH'] + ':' + install_dir + '/share' + ':' + gazebo_models_path
    else:
        os.environ['GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH'] = install_dir + "/share" + ':' + gazebo_models_path

    if 'GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH' in os.environ: #Add Gazebo Plugin Path to "GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH". So Gazebo can load the plugins. Otherwise gazebo is not able to find them.
        os.environ['GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH'] = os.environ['GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH'] + ':' + install_dir + '/lib'
    else:
        os.environ['GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH'] = install_dir + '/lib'


    print("Path pkg_gazebo_ros==", pkg_gazebo_ros)
    print("GAZEBO_MODELS_PATH=="+str(os.environ["GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH"])) #Visualize Generated Path to check them if they are right.
    print("GAZEBO_PLUGINS_PATH=="+str(os.environ["GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH"])) #Visualize Generated Path to check them if they are right.

    # Gazebo launch. Setting Path to Launch File we want to start. "We want to start the gazebo.launch.py File in the directory launch from the package "pkg_gazebo_ros" ""
    gazebo = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
            os.path.join(pkg_gazebo_ros, 'launch', 'gazebo.launch.py'),
        )
    )

    # # gazebo Version from the gazebo_ros2_control_demos -> cart_example_position.launch.py Beispiel. -> Macht keinen Unterschied.
    # gazebo = IncludeLaunchDescription(
    #     PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
    #         get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros'), 'launch'), '/gazebo.launch.py']),
    #     )
    

    return LaunchDescription([
        #Setting "our" world "box_bot_empty.world" as world we want to launch
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'world',
        default_value=[os.path.join(pkg_box_bot_gazebo, 'worlds', 'raf_empty.world'), ''],
        description='SDF world file'),

        gazebo
    ])
```

**Code of Launch-File #2:**
Second Launch file "`publish_urdf.launch.py`" starts a robot_state_publisher node to publish urdf description of my model and a (normally redundant) controller manager:

```
# This launch will:
# Publish the content of the URDF in the robot_description topic using the "robot_state_publish_node"
# Publish the static transforms between links with the "robot_state_publish_node"

import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription

from launch.substitutions import Command

from launch_ros.actions import Node

#Added because of ros2_control

from launch.substitutions import FindExecutable, LaunchConfiguration, PathJoinSubstitution
from launch.conditions import IfCondition
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare

from launch.actions import TimerAction #Für die Verzögerung des Controller_Manager notwendig

# this is the function launch system will look for
def generate_launch_description():

    ##### DATA INPUT START #####
    urdf_file = 'model_picker.urdf'
    package_description = 'model_picker_description'
    ##### DATA INPUT END #####

    print("Fetching URDF ==>")
    robot_desc_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_description), "urdf", urdf_file)

    with open(robot_desc_path, 'r') as urdf_file:
        urdf_file_content = urdf_file.read()
    
    # print("urdf_file_content enthält:")
    # print(urdf_file_content)

    # print("Hier ist was in robot_desc_path steht:")
    # print(robot_desc_path)

    #Robot State Publisher Command(['xacro', str(robot_desc_path)]
    robot_state_publisher_node = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        name='robot_state_publisher_node',
        emulate_tty=True,
        parameters=[{'use_sim_time': True, 'robot_description': urdf_file_content}],
        output="screen"
    )

    #Added because of ros2_control
    #Pfad zur "picker_controller.yaml" raussuchen und in die Variable "picker_controller" packen
    path_picker_controller_config = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [
            FindPackageShare("model_picker_description"),
            "config",
            "picker_controllers.yaml",
        ]
    )

    controller_manager_node = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="ros2_control_node",
        parameters=[{'use_sim_time': True, 'robot_description': urdf_file_content}, path_picker_controller_config],
        output={
            "stdout": "screen",
            "stderr": "screen",
        },
    )

    delayed_controller_manager = TimerAction(period=10.0, actions=[controller_manager_node]) # Verzögert die Ausführung des Controller manager Nodeu m 3 Sekunden. Notwendig, damit robot state publisher vorher fertig ist. Sonst startet der Controller Manager nicht und nichts funktioniert.

    #create and return launch description object
    return LaunchDescription(
        [
            robot_state_publisher_node,
            controller_manager_node,
            delayed_controller_manager
        ]
    )
```

Comment: Be ware that foxy is end-of-life and not officially supported any more.

Comment: Can you launch the demos provided with gazebo_ros2_control? https://github.com/ros-controls/gazebo_ros2_control/tree/foxy

Comment: Yes i can launch the demos of gazebo_ros2_control.
I tested it with:                  

`ros2 launch gazebo_ros2_control_demos cart_example_position.launch.py`
`ros2 run gazebo_ros2_control_demos example_position`

It works fine. The Cart moves along the Line.

Comment: I just added information about my two launch-Files i use at the end of my initial post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the long pause, i was trying stuff and wanted to write an answer when i had something to say.

As far as i see it, the problem of not loading the .YAML-File is solved.

All i did was changing my *.urdf file to a *.urdf.xacro file.
To do this i did the following:

**1. Change the Ending of the file**

```
`*.urdf -> *.urdf.xacro`
```

**2. Add the Xacro Reference to the -tag inside the file**

```
Old:

`<robot name="model_picker_gestaenge">`

` ... `

`<robot/>`


New:

`<robot xmlns:xacro="https://wiki.ros.org/xacro.org" name="model_picker_gestaenge>`

` ... `

`<robot/>`
```

**3. Change Parsing Code**

Old:

> 

```
##### DATA INPUT START #####
urdf_file = 'model_picker.urdf'
package_description = 'model_picker_description'
##### DATA INPUT END #####

print("Fetching URDF ==>")
robot_desc_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_description), "urdf", urdf_file)

with open(robot_desc_path, 'r') as urdf_file:
    urdf_file_content = urdf_file.read()

# print("urdf_file_content enthält:")
# print(urdf_file_content)

# print("Hier ist was in robot_desc_path steht:")
# print(robot_desc_path)

#Robot State Publisher Command(['xacro', str(robot_desc_path)]
robot_state_publisher_node = Node(
    package='robot_state_publisher',
    executable='robot_state_publisher',
    name='robot_state_publisher_node',
    emulate_tty=True,
    parameters=[{'use_sim_time': True, 'robot_description': urdf_file_content}],
    output="screen"
)
```

> 

New:

> 

```
##### DATA INPUT START #####
xacro_file = 'model_picker.urdf.xacro'
package_description = 'model_picker_description'
##### DATA INPUT END #####

print("Fetching URDF ==>")
#Getting Path of the xacro file
xacro_file_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_description), "urdf", xacro_file)

#Convertig *.xacro-File into urdf-String via "xacro" Command -> Ergebnis ist der String der URDF Datei + Wrapping String in ParameterValue so that roslaunch system will not falsely interpret it as a .yaml-File during parsing.
urdf_file_content = launch.substitutions.Command(['xacro', " " , xacro_file_path])

#Wrapping String in ParameterValue so that roslaunch system will not falsely interpret it as a .yaml-File during parsing.
urdf_file_content_wrapped = launch_ros.descriptions.ParameterValue( urdf_file_content, value_type=str)

#Erstellen des dictionaries für das parsen der robot_description
robot_description = [{'robot_description': urdf_file_content_wrapped}]


#Robot State Publisher Command(['xacro', str(robot_desc_path)]
robot_state_publisher_node = Node(
    package='robot_state_publisher',
    executable='robot_state_publisher',
    name='robot_state_publisher_node',
    emulate_tty=True,
    parameters=robot_description,
    output="screen"
)
```

Now the .YAML File is found under the path i gave it and loaded.
Now i have a different error message which i count as progress. :-)

Can somebody explain to me why it makes such a huge difference?
Or does somebody has an assumption?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something is wrong with your launch file. Why do you create a ros2_control_node? This is not necessary, because gazebo_ros2_control instantiates the controller manager (you should see a node called `/controller_manager` and `/gazebo_ros2_control`). See the `cart_example_position.launch.py` file.

Regarding the error while loading the parameter file: Try to hardcode the path, just to be sure that this is not related to some error with the find-macro.

Comment: Yes i read it that the gazebo_ros2_control plugin instantiates the controller manager. I also tried it with and without the ros2_control_node. But it never worked and i never saw the start of a controller manager in my ros2 package to this day.
I will try your suggestion and report to you

Comment: I created a ros2_control_node because i did not see one after i launched the package. It was a try to get a /controller_manager node.

I am able to start the example "cart_example_position.launch.py" I am checking and comparing the code to my code right now. So far i tried adding dependencies to package.xml, adapting gazebo node and robot_state_publisher node. No success so far.

I hardcoded the path within the <ros2_control>-tags already. It makes no difference. Is it possible that the variable "path_picker_controller_config" overwrote it somehow?

Comment: You have to use the controller manager from gazebo_ros2_control, and don't launch a different node as you have done in your launch file.

Comment: And I don't see you spawning your robot, have a look at the launch file https://github.com/ros-controls/gazebo_ros2_control/blob/2262ffca70c24b8b05ed00be4b3be0e5b881e389/gazebo_ros2_control_demos/launch/cart_example_position.launch.py#L54-L57

Comment: You are right.
I am currently working on finding out which nodes i need for a "bare bone" launch without errors and a hardware_interface consisting of one joint.
On which i can expand my definition of the hardware interface and so on.
I orient myself on the demo "gazebo_ros2_control_demos/cart_example_position.launch.py "
But still getting errors. 
I will open a new issue if i can't handle them.