# the class gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem with base class type hardware_interface::SystemInterface does not exist

Tags: ros-humble, gazebo-11, controller-manager, ros2-control, gazebo-ros2-control

I have seen two posts with talking about this issue but none of them have been answered.

[class gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem with base class type hardware_interface::SystemInterface does not exist](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/103767/class-gazebo-ros2-control-gazebosystem-with-base-class-type-hardware-interface)
and
[ROS2/Gazebo/ros2_control: Class gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem does not exist](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/105880/ros2-gazebo-ros2-control-class-gazebo-ros2-control-gazebosystem-does-not-exist)

I am trying to create a controller using gazebo_ros2_control. I am using ROS2 Humble, Gazebo 11 and Ubuntu 22.04.

The error I am getting is as follows
"According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem with base class type hardware_interface::SystemInterface does not exist. Declared types are  fake_components/GenericSystem mock_components/GenericSystem test_hardware_components/TestSystemCommandModes test_hardware_components/TestTwoJointSystem test_system"

I have ros2_control installed and it is the correct branch for my ROS2 distro. I can run the ros2_control_demos successfully.

Here is the ROS2 control portion of my xacro file

```
    <ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">
      <hardware>
        <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
      </hardware>
      <joint name="pitch_mass_joint">
        <command_interface name="position">
          <param name="min">${pitch_mass_limit_lower}</param>
      <param name="max">${pitch_mass_limit_upper}</param>
        </command_interface>
        <state_interface name="position"/>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        <state_interface name="effort"/>
      </joint>

      <joint name="port_aileron_joint">
        <command_interface name="position">
          <param name="min">${aileron_limit_lower}</param>
      <param name="max">${aileron_limit_upper}</param>
        </command_interface>
        <state_interface name="position"/>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        <state_interface name="effort"/>
      </joint>

      <joint name="port_flap_joint">
        <command_interface name="position">
          <param name="min">${flap_limit_lower}</param>
      <param name="max">${flap_limit_upper}</param>
        </command_interface>
        <state_interface name="position"/>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        <state_interface name="effort"/>
      </joint>

      <joint name="stbd_aileron_joint">
        <command_interface name="position">
          <param name="min">${aileron_limit_lower}</param>
      <param name="max">${aileron_limit_upper}</param>
        </command_interface>
        <state_interface name="position"/>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        <state_interface name="effort"/>
      </joint>

      <joint name="stbd_flap_joint">
        <command_interface name="position">
          <param name="min">${flap_limit_lower}</param>
      <param name="max">${flap_limit_upper}</param>
        </command_interface>
        <state_interface name="position"/>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        <state_interface name="effort"/>
      </joint>
    </ros2_control>

   <gazebo>
       <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control" >
          <parameters>$(find zray_bringup)/config/controller_configuration.yaml</parameters>
       </plugin>
   </gazebo>
```

Here is my config file

```
gazebo_ros2_control:
  ros__parameters:
    hardware_interface: gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem
    robot_description: robot_description
    
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 100 #Hz

    joint_trajectory_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

joint_trajectory_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - pitch_mass_joint
      - port_aileron_joint
      - port_flap_joint
      - stbd_aileron_joint
      - stbd_flap_joint
    interface_name: position
    command_interfaces:
      - position
    state_interfaces:
      - position
      - velocity
```

and here is my launch file

```
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, ExecuteProcess
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch_ros.actions import Node

import xacro

def generate_launch_description():

    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time', default='false')

    urdf_file_name = 'zray.urdf.xacro'
    urdf = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory('zray'),
        urdf_file_name)
    #with open(urdf, 'r') as infp:
    #    robot_desc = infp.read()

    robot_description_config = xacro.process_file(urdf)
    robot_desc = robot_description_config.toxml()

    controller_config_file_name = 'controller_configuration.yaml'
    controller_config = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory('zray_bringup'), 'config',
        controller_config_file_name)
        
    
    load_joint_state_controller = ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=['ros2', 'control', 'load_controller', '--set-state', 'active', 'joint_state_broadcaster'],
        output='screen'
    )
    
    load_joint_trajectory_controller = ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=['ros2', 'control', 'load_controller', '--set-state', 'active', 'joint_trajectory_controller'],
        output='screen'
    )
    
    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_sim_time',
            default_value='false',
            description='Use simulation (Gazebo) clock if true'),
        Node(
            package='robot_state_publisher',
            executable='robot_state_publisher',
            name='robot_state_publisher',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time, 'robot_description': robot_desc}],
            arguments=[robot_desc]),
        Node(
            package='zray',
            executable='state_publisher',
            name='state_publisher',
            output='screen'),

        Node(
            package='controller_manager',
            executable='ros2_control_node',
            parameters=[{'robot_description': robot_desc}, controller_config],
            output='screen'),
            
        load_joint_state_controller, load_joint_trajectory_controller,                

    ])
```

I have noticed something else which my be pointing to the same underlying issue. I have been following tutorials on ros2_control pipeline in Gazebo from the Construct.
https://youtu.be/xBhYHOSxMOk?si=JpdWSoqeRTptElVd&t=2566

When I set the state of the joint_state_broadcaster to 'start'

```
cmd=['ros2','control','load_controller','--set-state','start','joint_state_broadcaster'], ...
```

I get
"ros2 control load_controller: error: argument --set-state: invalid choice: 'start' (choose from 'configured', 'inactive', 'active')"

It seem to work fine for everyone else, so it appears like I have some versioning issue. Why would I not have 'start' to chose from? I have tried everything I can think of to find it with no luck.

I appreciate any help or insight as I am truly stuck. For completeness I am attaching the full ROS info log incase that is of any help.

Thanks

Gideon

```
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [103499]
[INFO] [state_publisher-2]: process started with pid [103501]
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-3]: process started with pid [103503]
[INFO] [ros2-4]: process started with pid [103505]
[INFO] [ros2-5]: process started with pid [103507]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-6]: process started with pid [103509]
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1706740525.742803775] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1706740525.742904027] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment dummy_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1706740525.742919349] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment pitch_mass_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1706740525.742928839] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment port_aileron_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1706740525.742936937] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment port_flap_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1706740525.742944622] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment stbd_aileron_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1706740525.742951954] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment stbd_flap_link
[ros2_control_node-3] [INFO] [1706740525.746934847] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'GazeboSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-3] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pluginlib::LibraryLoadException'
[ros2_control_node-3]   what():  According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem with base class type hardware_interface::SystemInterface does not exist. Declared types are  fake_components/GenericSystem mock_components/GenericSystem test_hardware_components/TestSystemCommandModes test_hardware_components/TestTwoJointSystem test_system
[ros2_control_node-3] Stack trace (most recent call last):
[ros2_control_node-3] #16   Object "", at 0xffffffffffffffff, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #15   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x56420a88ed84, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #14   Source "../csu/libc-start.c", line 392, in __libc_start_main_impl [0x7f2d8fc29e3f]
[ros2_control_node-3] #13   Source "../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h", line 58, in __libc_start_call_main [0x7f2d8fc29d8f]
[ros2_control_node-3] #12   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x56420a88e89e, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #11   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libcontroller_manager.so", at 0x7f2d90635661, in controller_manager::ControllerManager::ControllerManager(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rclcpp::NodeOptions const&)
[ros2_control_node-3] #10   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libcontroller_manager.so", at 0x7f2d90634747, in controller_manager::ControllerManager::init_resource_manager(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
[ros2_control_node-3] #9    Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x7f2d902d1d7f, in hardware_interface::ResourceManager::load_urdf(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)
[ros2_control_node-3] #8    Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x7f2d902d040e, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #7    Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x7f2d902af6b0, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #6    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f2d900ae4d7, in __cxa_throw
[ros2_control_node-3] #5    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f2d900ae276, in std::terminate()
[ros2_control_node-3] #4    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f2d900ae20b, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #3    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f2d900a2b9d, in 
[ros2_control_node-3] #2    Source "./stdlib/abort.c", line 79, in abort [0x7f2d8fc287f2]
[ros2_control_node-3] #1    Source "../sysdeps/posix/raise.c", line 26, in raise [0x7f2d8fc42475]
[ros2_control_node-3] #0  | Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 89, in __pthread_kill_internal
[ros2_control_node-3]     | Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 78, in __pthread_kill_implementation
[ros2_control_node-3]       Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 44, in __pthread_kill [0x7f2d8fc969fc]
[ros2_control_node-3] Aborted (Signal sent by tkill() 103503 1000)
[state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1706740526.045458968] [state_publisher]: state_publisher started
[spawn_entity.py-6] [INFO] [1706740526.062908834] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[spawn_entity.py-6] [INFO] [1706740526.063390831] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity published on topic /robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-6] /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/qos.py:307: UserWarning: DurabilityPolicy.RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_TRANSIENT_LOCAL is deprecated. Use DurabilityPolicy.TRANSIENT_LOCAL instead.
[spawn_entity.py-6]   warnings.warn(
[spawn_entity.py-6] [INFO] [1706740526.065729092] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for entity xml on /robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-6] [INFO] [1706740526.076636921] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-6] [INFO] [1706740526.076959611] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-6] [INFO] [1706740526.080424535] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-6] [INFO] [1706740526.282578617] [spawn_entity]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [zray-62706]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-6]: process has finished cleanly [pid 103509]
[ros2-4] Sucessfully loaded controller joint_state_broadcaster into state active
[INFO] [ros2-4]: process has finished cleanly [pid 103505]
[ERROR] [ros2_control_node-3]: process has died [pid 103503, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params_76vi2_zj --params-file /home/gideon/zray_ws/src/zray_bringup/config/controller_configuration.yaml'].
[ros2-5] Sucessfully loaded controller joint_trajectory_controller into state active
[INFO] [ros2-5]: process has finished cleanly [pid 103507]
```

Answer (score 0):

Btw: Both questions have been answered.

Why do you use a ros2_control_node? (see the answers in the questions you mentioned).

Comment: There are two answers on the first link, one is actually a question asking if ros2 control demos are working, and the other said "Thanks for help and your answers. I almost solve the problems." So I figured out there was more to sort out. I appreciate you pointing out the ros2_control_node not needing to be there. Removing it has cleared up the issue. I saw it in a tutorial. Is that only used when launching a real robot? Thanks

Comment: The ros2_control_node is a wrapper around the [controller_manager](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html#controller-manager). The gazebo_ros2_control directly creates an instance of the controller manager class, hence, there is no need for an additional ros2_control_node.